# App icons are not shown in top bar after upgrade Ubuntu to 22.04

Tags: gnome, icons, ubuntu-gnome

There are several apps such as slack, safeeyes, skype and etc. that when running in background, you can see the icon on the top bar. But after updatig my Ubuntu from 20.04 to 22.04 it is not shown any more. I tried reinstalling the apps, but it didn't work.
[image]

Comment: if you feel up to it - https://fosspost.org/custom-system-tray-icon-indicator-linux/